# Convert String Array to Array Object with keys and values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to convert a string array like that:

```
const arr = [
  "name:Adam age:20 height:180cm",
  "name:Sally age:30 height:170cm",
  "name:Mike age:35 height:185cm",
  "name:David age:40 height:190cm"
];
```

to this array that includes object with keys and values like that below:

```
var obj = [
  {name:'Adam', age:20, height:'180cm'},
  {name:'Sally', age:30, height:'170cm'},
  {name:'Mike', age:35, height:'185cm'},
  {name:'David', age:40, height:'190cm'}
];
```

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried some for loop to initilaize values and key after split the strings. And also I tried Object.assign

Comment: You should include what you tried **in the question**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
  "name:Adam age:20 height:180cm",
  "name:Sally age:30 height:170cm",
  "name:Mike age:35 height:185cm",
  "name:David age:40 height:190cm"
]

let result = arr.map(e => Object.fromEntries(e.split(' ').map(n=>n.split(":"))))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This will work, unless there are spaces or colons `:` in the data, of course, but that's a validation issue. Best would be to avoid to serialize the data in this "format" from the begining.

Comment: That was more intended to OP, this answer is good for the problem asked :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use array map and split method to get your result.

```js
const arr = [
  'name:Adam age:20 height:180cm',
  'name:Sally age:30 height:170cm',
  'name:Mike age:35 height:185cm',
  'name:David age:40 height:190cm',
];

const ret = arr.map((x) => {
  const obj = {};
  const a = x.split(' ');
  a.forEach((y) => {
    const [key, value] = y.split(':');
    obj[key] = key === 'age' ? +value : value;
  });
  return obj;
});
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the bad naming as I did this in a hurry but something like this should help:

```js
s = "name:Adam age:20 height:180cm";
a = s.split(" ");
c = a.map(item => {
    pair = item.split(":");
    key = "\"" + pair[0] + "\"";
    value = "\"" + pair[1] + "\"";
    return key + ":" + value;
});
s = c.join(",");
s = "{" + s + "}";
o = JSON.parse(s);
console.log(o)
```

At the end `o` should be the object you want.

Comment: I took the liberty of turning your code into an executable snippet. FYI, there is this "Snippet" button available for HTML / JS code. And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thanks! I realized eventually that I can do that, when I saw that my answer is the only one that does not do that.